# Magento 1.9.1 after upgrade 1.9.2.4 PHP Fatal error: Class 'Mpdf_Mpdfstart' not found

Tags: php, magento, pdf

During magento upgrade from 1.9.1 to upgrade  1.9.2.4, I got the following error in my pdf generator class. I am using "EaDesign PDF" library and I got the issue on "Mpdf_Mpdfstart" constructor.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mpdf_Mpdfstart' not found in
>       app/code/local/EaDesign/PdfGenerator/Model/Entity/Pdfgenerator.php
>       on line 67.

```
$pdf = new Mpdf_Mpdfstart('', $this->pdfPaperFormat(), 8, '', $left, $right, $top, $bottom);
$pdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 0;
$pdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
return $pdf;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the extension `EADesign_PdfGenerator` is a paid extension with no open source code you need to contact [EADesign](https://www.eadesign.ro/en/magento-extensions/magento-invoice-pdf-generator.html) directly and ask for support. You paid for the extension so they need to give you support.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. Make sure you have the Mpdf library folder in the folder /lib in the Magento root.